# space between lines \huge

Tags: line-spacing

I created a title page for my thesis. 
I used the code `\huge` for title. But, my title has words with accents. So, the space between first e second line is different than second and third line.

[image]

Comment: Could you give a Minimal Working Example of code producing such a result? Normally inteline spacing has nothing to do with the presence or not of accented letters.

Answer (score 4):

TeX uses the `\baselineskip` setting that is active at the end of the paragraph. If the group, where `\huge` is set, is closed earlier, then the settings before (`\normalsize`?) is used, too small for huge text. Then TeX switches to `\lineskip` that separates the lines, usually `1pt`. The first line has a cedilla and the second line accented characters. Thus the space looks greater, but the space between the cedilla and the accent is probably just 1pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
{
  \centering
  \huge
  MODIFICA\c C\~AO DE CARBONATO DE\\
  C\'ALCIO NATURAL COM S\'ILICA PARA\\
  APLICA\c C\~OES EM PAPEL
  \par % close paragraph explicitly before group end
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Without MWE I am only guessing the real source of the problem. However, I am nearly sure that it is not the matter of accented letters, but the lack of final `\par` in a structure producing the title, e.g.

```
\begin{center}
\huge
First line\\
Second line\\
Third line
\par % or free line
\end{center}
```

Comment: `\par` isn't needed in this case (well it is, needed but `\end{center}` supplies one so an extra one is not neeed).